# Taking derivative of the sum: A short and general derivation question

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

What is the result of the derivative

$\frac{\partial \sum_i x_i}{\partial x_i} $

Thank you

Comment: I'd probably use a different dummy/summation index upstairs so that it's not redundant with the one down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One trick to understanding complicated notation is to do a couple of special cases.  For instance, set $n=3$.  What is the derivative of $x_1+x_2+x_3$ with respect to $x_1$? To $x_2$? To $x_3$?  I think you will see a pattern there that can be generalized.

In general, for each $j$,
$$
    \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i 
   =\sum\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial x_j} 
$$
The coordinates are independent variables, so the derivative of any of them with respect to any other one of them is zero.  So $\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial x_j} = 0$ if $i \neq j$.  If $i=j$, though, the variables are exactly the same, and the derivative is one.  There's a special name for this kind of symbol, called the **Kronecker delta:**
$$
    \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial x_j}  = \delta_{ij} = \begin{cases} 0 & i \neq j \\ 1 & i = j \end{cases}
$$
So we want to find $\sum_{i=1}^n \delta_{ij}$.

Here's the part which I found confusing at first: we don't know what $i$ is!  But we do know that exactly one of the indices $j=1,2, \dots n$ is equal to $i$.  So $\sum_{i=1}^n \delta_{ij}$ is summing one $1$ and $n-1$ zeroes.  Therefore,
$$
     \sum_{i=1}^n \delta_{ij}=1
$$

Comment: Then each one is equal to one. But how can I express it in general? I am confused